# Regular Expression for numbers and letters unless all digits are identical

Tags: php, regex

I have an regular expression:

```
^(?!(?:(\d)\1+[ -]*)+$)\d[\d- ]+$
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/sB1tK3/1

As you can see it not allowing strings which have all characters identical, but it checks only numbers.

How would I make that same regex checks letters (dashes and spaces shoud be still allowed) e.g:

aaaaa - it's not ok

aa-aaa-aaa-aaaaa - it's not OK

ababab - it's OK

ab-ab-ab - it's OK

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\w` in place of `\d` to match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`:

```
^(?!(?:(\w)\1+[ -]*)+$)\w[\w -]+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sB1tK3/3)